# failed to map state to props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-redux to change the state of my react application.I also using a authguard to prevent access to my routes.I am trying to map my current state using connect in react-redux.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { Redirect,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
   props.userLoginStatus==1
      ? <Redirect to='/home' />
      : <Component {...props} />
  )} />
)
const mapStateProps=(state)=> {
    console.log(state.loginDetails.status);
    return {
        userLoginStatus:state.loginDetails.status
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

when i print the status value in state, it shows value of 1.But when i check it with using 'props.userLoginstatus',it always returns false.What the issue here is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props.userLoginStatus` is not used correctly since, `props` here refer to the `router props` and not the `PrivateRoute` props, you can actually destructure the `userLoginStatus` prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { Redirect,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, userLoginStatus, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
   userLoginStatus==1
      ? <Redirect to='/home' />
      : <Component {...props} />
  )} />
)
const mapStateProps=(state)=> {
    console.log(state.loginDetails.status);
    return {
        userLoginStatus:state.loginDetails.status
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateProps)(PrivateRoute);
```